# Pass Identity user object to AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

How to pass full Identity User object to AuthorizationFilterAttribute from CustomOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.

```
public class CustomOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider 
{       
    public override Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
          var appUserManager = 
          context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
          var identity = context.Ticket.Identity;
          var user = appUserManager.FindByIdAsync(identity.GetUserId()).Result;
          context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("PSK", user.PSK));
          return base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    }
}

public class TwoFactorAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
   public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext 
   actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as 
       ClaimsPrincipal;
       var psk= principal?.FindFirst("psk").Value; //I want to read full object rather than individual property
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can create some utility class, Where you can get the token and read all claims and then send it, Then Inject that utility in `TwoFactorAuthorizeAttribute` class on construct and call that method to get the list.

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity; 
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
```

Comment: var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;